# Login on lid close event

Tags: login, laptop, lid

Very odd question, but I'd like to know what to enter into a lid script executed by something in `/etc/acpi/events/` to run a command to log in to a user.

I have a magnetic implant and I think it'd be interesting to be able to automatically log in when I place my finger on the lid magnet sensor on my laptop. Ignoring any security risks, is this possible? I won't be using this regularly.

Comment: You could simply use auto-login without need for user ID or password.

Comment: But that won’t be triggered by my placing my magnet over the laptop’s sensor, which is what I’m trying to do